# Multiple WebViews + Binding the Source Property

Tags: c#, mvvm, webview, windows-store-apps, mvvm-light

I am creating an application where the user will be able to navigate between multiple WebViews. However only one WebView will be visible and the rest are collapsed.

So in my code behind I have an array of WebViews. The main reason for doing this is I would like to keep the state of a WebView. So if the user has a form filled out or  scrolls to a specific location on the page, it will still be like that when that webview is collapsed and brought into view again.

I am able to achieve this by setting the Source property of the WebView manually but not by binding it to a property in my ViewModel. All the WebViews are bound to the same source property and I believe that is why it isn't working properly with the binding method. Whenever the source property changes, all the WebViews get updated accordingly.

I also tried to keep track of the source for each WebView and remove the binding when it gets collapsed and add it again when it gets visible but this just seems to reload the page again.

Would there be any way of achieving this using binding? Any help is appreciated, thank you!